# does Webview remember the session information?

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using one of those online application builders to build an android application. But from what i have researched, online application builders are used to build hybrid mobile applications. Since these are HTML files, they use the inApp browser and are rendered in WebView. So, My question is - Is webview/inApp Browser capable of remembering the session information? suppose I have users log into a website by displaying it in a webview. Will the users be still logged in if they visit the website a second time? When I test these applications in an online environment running inside a fully-fledged browser, the application seems to remember the user. I suspect this is because the test environment itself is contained within the browser which stores the session information. So, If a user was to sign into a website on a real device, will he/she be required to sign in every time the user launches an application? or will he/she remain signed in until sign out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on Which platform you are using to create app. Each online platform carries their own implementation policy.

Android provides `Javascript Interface` for interaction between javascript code in html and java code.

**Is webview/inApp Browser capable of remembering the session information?**

> Yes,Session can be stored in app itself using `javascript interface`.

Environment of inApp Browser and External browser is total independent until cookies are used.

**If a user was to sign into a website on a real device, will he/she be required to sign in every time the user launches an application?**

> Depends on implementation. If app is designed to save login session then user will not be asked to sign in again.

Comment: thanks for the answer man..I am using appery.io and I think they do provide the ability to remember the session. They had the option to download their app tester which itself is an android application, meaning that if it runs my app for testing, it will be using the WebView... So, even if I log out of the tester,log in again and then test the app by launching it, it displays the user specific homepage. So I guess it does remember :-)..however testing on a real device would be the definitive way of judging that...don't you think?

Comment: it's "real" device, not "read"... and by that I mean testing on an actual device and not in virtual test environments/emulators

Comment: my bad, i was intended to write real.

Answer (score 0):

### **Check if the post domain matches the original domain**

I had a similar issue that took me forever to debug.

One tip I would give to anyone with the same issue is to check where the form is being posted to.

For instance if you are loading **domain.com** and the form is posting to **www.domain.com** your app will be searching for the session data in **domain.com** but the session info will live in **www.domain.com**.

Make sure your origin and post domains match up

Took me many hours and many cups of coffee to figure out this seemingly simple issue.